# golang rpc can't find service

Tags: go, rpc

I can't find the error in this code.
When i run it, i get `Error in Broker.Connect: rpc: can't find service Broker.Connect`. 
I know that this message means that when the client try to call the remote procedure Connect he doesn't find it. But i don't understand why. I'm sure that i'm publishing the procedure Connect correctly.

I show you my code.
I think something simple is missing, but I just can't understand what.

This is the server's interface i'm trying to publish:

```
package Broker

import (
    "MyRand/Rand"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
)

type ConsumerId struct {
    Name string
    Address string
}

type Broker int

func (b *Broker)Connect(s string, r *ConsumerId) error{
    r.Name = Rand.String(10)
    CL.lock.Lock()
    exists := true
    for exists {
        e := CL.list.Front()
        for i := 0; i < CL.list.Len(); i++ {
            var v ConsumerId = e.Value.(ConsumerId)
            if s == v.Address {
                if v.Name != r.Name {
                    portNumber := rand.Intn(1000) + rand.Intn(9000)
                    s = strconv.Itoa(portNumber)
                    break
                } else {
                    continue
                }
            }
            if i == CL.list.Len() -1 {
                exists = false
            }
            e = e.Next()
        }
    }
    r.Address = s
    CL.list.PushBack(r)
    CL.lock.Unlock()

    fmt.Println("Host connected: " + s)
    return nil
}
```

This is the code that publish the method:

```
package Broker

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/rpc"
    "sync"
)

type ConsumerList struct {
    lock sync.RWMutex
    list list.List
}

const ServerAddr = ":1234"

var CL *ConsumerList
var b *Broker
var l net.Listener
var e error

func initialization(){
    CL = new(ConsumerList)
    b = new(Broker)
    server := rpc.NewServer()
    e = server.RegisterName("Broker", b)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("Format of service Broker is not correct: ", e)
    }
    // Listen for incoming tcp packets on specified port.
    l, e = net.Listen("tcp", ServerAddr)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("Listen error:", e)
    }
}

func FuncBroker() {
    initialization()
    for {
        fmt.Println("Broker.go42")
        rpc.Accept(l)
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the code that call the procedure and trigger the error:

```
package Consumer

import (
    "MyProject/Broker"
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net"
    "net/rpc"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

var subscriptions *list.List
var id Broker.ConsumerId
var client *rpc.Client
var e error

func connect(){
    client, e := rpc.Dial("tcp", "localhost" + Broker.ServerAddr)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error in dialing: ", e)
    }
    portN := 1000+rand.Intn(8999)
    portNString := strconv.Itoa(portN)
    e = client.Call("Broker.Connect", portNString, &id)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error in Broker.Connect: ", e)
    }
}


func FuncConsumer(){
    connect()
    defer client.Close()
//  go exposeInterface()

    subscriptions = new(list.List)
//  userCommands()
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Clearly when I run the code, I first run the broker and after that the consumer.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: You registered "Server" as the name of the service, not "Broker".

Comment: @BurakSerdar, i edit because that was a test. It doesn't work even with "Broker".

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is calling `accept` using `rpc.Accept(l)`, i correct this writing `server.Accept(l)` where `server` is the value taken here `server := rpc.NewServer()`.